# Spring Security PreAuthorize Custom Method Bean resolver is not registered?

Tags: spring, security, methods, spring-security, spring-java-config

Im just learning Spring, going through tutorials and testing possibilities. One of my goals is to secure a Service Method using a Custom Method and the PreAuthorize annotation. Unfortunaly the Bean holding the custom Method cannot be resolved and I dont know why. Maybe someone can see the error at first sight.

Bean holding the custom Method:

```
@Component("mySecurityService")
public class MySecurityService {
    public boolean hasPermission() {
        return true; //simple implementation just to look if has permission is called
    }
}
```

Service to be Secured:

```
public interface OrderService {

  @PreAuthorize("@mySecurityService.hasPermission()")
  public AllOrdersEvent requestAllOrders(RequestAllOrdersEvent requestAllCurrentOrdersEvent);

  public OrderDetailsEvent requestOrderDetails(RequestOrderDetailsEvent requestOrderDetailsEvent);

  public OrderStatusEvent requestOrderStatus(RequestOrderStatusEvent requestOrderStatusEvent);

  public OrderCreatedEvent createOrder(CreateOrderEvent event);

  public OrderUpdatedEvent setOrderPayment(SetOrderPaymentEvent setOrderPaymentEvent);

  public OrderDeletedEvent deleteOrder(DeleteOrderEvent deleteOrderEvent);

}
```

Java Security Config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
       .withUser("letsnosh").password("noshing").roles("USER");
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Bean(name = "mySecurityService")
  MySecurityService createSecurityService(){return new MySecurityService();}

@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     /*
   http.authorizeUrls()
    .antMatchers("/aggregators*//**//**").hasRole("USER")
    .anyRequest().anonymous()
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
      */

  }
}
```

Error:

```
 No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'mySecurityService'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I solved the problem. It was connected to the Version of Spring Security.

I got the Version from the official Spring Rest Tutotrial : **3.2.0.M2**

In this version I had to declare the Security Context as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("letsnosh").password("noshing").roles("USER");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeUrls()
        .antMatchers("/aggregators/**").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().anonymous()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
  }
}
```

Here the error was thrown.

But using a newer Version of Spring Security: **3.2.5.RELEASE**
I could declare the Config this way:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   http.authorizeUrls()
        .antMatchers("/aggregators*//**//**").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().anonymous()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();


  }
```

And the bean could be resolved, using either @Component Annotaions directly on the MySecurityService class or @Bean annotations on a config class method which returns a MySecurityService instance.